# Is this sequence unbounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

---

**Problem.**
Suppose that a sequence $\{a_n\}_{(n\ge 1)}$ is a strict increasing sequence of positive integers such that
$$\forall i,\phantom{;}j(i\neq j);\phantom{;}a_i \not\mid a_j$$
Prove that $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ is unbounded.

---

I had tried various kinds of ways but I couldn't prove the problem; Instead of it, I proved the following result, which is weaker than the original problem;

---

**Weaker result I proved.**
Suppose that a sequence $\{a_n\}_{(n\ge 1)}$ is a strict increasing sequence of positive integers such that
$$\forall i,\phantom{;}j(i\neq j);\phantom{;}\color{blue}{\gcd(a_i, a_j)=1}$$
Then $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ is unbounded.

---

I used Chinese remainder theorem to prove this. (I'll post it if you want it.) I tried to apply similar method for the original problem, but I failed;
Do you have some ideas for the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sequences of positive integers such that no element of the sequence is divisible by any other are called "primitive", and there has been a lot of work done figuring out how dense these sequences can be.  An early result of Erdős is that all primitive sequences must have lower density $0$, which immediately implies that they must have arbitrarily large gaps.  The proof is quite short and is given in ["Note on sequences of integers no one of which is divisible by any other", J. London Math. Soc. **10** (1935), pp. 126-128.](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1935-04.pdf)  There is also a similar result in [Felix Behrend, "On Sequences of Numbers not Divisible one by another", J. London Math. Soc. (1935) s1-10(1): 42-44 (paper is behind a pay wall.)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-10.37.42)

A later, more precise [result by Erdős, Sárközy and Szemerédi ("On a theorem of Behrend", J. Australian Mathematical Society, 7 (1967), pp. 9-16)](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1967-09.pdf) is that if $(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ is a primitive sequence, then
$$
\sum_{a_i<x} \frac{1}{a_i}=o(\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{\log \log x}}),
$$
and this is best possible in the sense that the fraction on the right-hand side cannot be divided by any $h(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x)=\infty.$